# Android Kotlin Glide Image Sizes Change when Scrolling

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-storage, android-glide, firebaseui

I am using Glide for Kotlin from Google as part of the Firebase suite.  I'm downloading jpg photos from Firebase.

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:6.4.0'
```

When I sroll, the images change size.  The faster I scroll, the smaller some images get.  I tried `fitCenter()` but that didnt seem to help.

```
        Glide.with(context!! /* context */)
            .load(figure.imagePrimaryFrontURLString)
            .apply(
                RequestOptions()
                    .placeholder(R.drawable.mytoybox_logo)
                    .fitCenter()
            )
            .into(holder.imageViewFigure)
```

Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include
            android:id="@+id/figure_photoFilters"
            layout="@layout/figure_filters"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="4dp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <SearchView
            android:id="@+id/searchView_FigurePhoto"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/figure_photoFilters" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/figurePhotoList_RecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/searchView_FigurePhoto" />

        <include
            android:id="@+id/progressBarWText"
            layout="@layout/progress_bar_with_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            android:id="@+id/adView"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            app:adSize="BANNER"
            app:adUnitId="xxx"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/figurePhotoList_RecyclerView">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

RecycleView Row Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView_Figure"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/figure_image"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:srcCompat="@drawable/mytoybox_logo" />

    <include
        android:id="@+id/layout_specifics_icons"
        layout="@layout/specifics_icons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@id/imageView_Figure"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/imageView_Figure" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Number"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_text_back"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/imageView_Figure"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imageView_Figure" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Figure_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_Figure"
        tools:text="Figure Name" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_Series_Name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView_Figure_Name"
        tools:text="Figure Name" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Specifics Icons

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/specifics_icons"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_HaveIcon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/check_white_on_green"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_WantIcon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/w_white_on_purple"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_HaveIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_SellIcon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/s_white_on_blue"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_WantIcon" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView_OrderIcon"
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:paddingStart="4dp"
        android:paddingEnd="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/o_white_on_orange"
        android:textColor="@color/primaryTextColor"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView_SellIcon" />

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Photo 1]

[image: Photo 2]

[image: Photo 3]

Comment: please post your item's layout (.xml) file, what you have written.

Comment: Added the layouts @Jatin K.

Answer (score 1):

The list items are being reused, and when you scroll down you bind a larger image which makes the ImageView layout taller (wrap_content). When you scroll back up Glide sees that taller size and tries to load an image that has that size. wrap_content only works if the didn't have a layout before, otherwise Glide reads the laid-out width/height and uses that as the target size. I usually recommend a holder.imageView.layout(0,0,0,0) to reset the size of the view/target and behave as if the list item was just inflated.